# troubles with unset to remove values from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to remove values from an array using unset, but it's not working properly

Say I have the following array

```
$array =
 [0]=>a
 [1]=>b
 [2]=>c
```

These items are being displayed in a table with the ability to remove one. Say I press on the value for 'b'. A hidden value ($removeID in this case) is set, and when I echo it 'b' appears, so I know that value is being sent properly.

Anyway, here is my code:

```
$removeID = $_POST['removeID']; //value to be removed. when echoe'd, it appears
$key = array_search($removeID,$array); //finds the key of the value
unset($array[$key]);
```

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly? It will remove the largest key in the array every time.

**edit- It appears as if the key isn't being properly found and is set to a boolean instead of  an integer**

I tried gettype($key) and it displayed as boolean. When I echo $removeID it displays the value that I want to remove from the array, so why is it that it can't find it when using array_search? Can I not search for variables?

Comment: what is the value of $key after the array_search?

Comment: @StefanNeubert hmm, doesn't look like it's setting. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because when I echo $removeID it displays. I tried putting using '$removeID' in the array_search function, but that didn't work. Can I not pass variables into it?

Comment: Does the array contain the String "a" or an object a? Maybe the array_search does not find the entry because of different data types.

Comment: I tried gettype on both the value of $array[0] and $removeID and they're both strings...Ok, just checked gettype of $key and it's a boolean. Can I convert that to an int?

Comment: If $key is boolean then it is probably *false* which means the value hasn't been found in the array.

Comment: What is the output of var_dump($array[1], $removeID, $array[1] == $removeID); after the first line?

Comment: Figured it out! I was echoing something incorrectly. Good tip!